# Shell detection of empty subshell

Tags: shell, subshell, shellcheck

[SC1143](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1143) suggests that commented parts of a wrapped shell command to be wrapped in a subshell.

Is the Posix shell "smart enough" to not launch a subshell when it sees that it does nothing? What about Bash and Zsh?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard implementation of the POSIX shell, you'd have to tell which particular one you mean.

Comment: I doubt if it's smart enough. I'm pretty sure it doesn't check the content of the command inside the backticks before it trys running it.

Comment: @ilkkachu "No standard implementation of POSIX shell". I don't understand. POSIX *is* a standard. Whichever shell implements this standard is POSIX-compliant. The distinction I made in the question was to know whether additions on top of POSIX made this optimization.

Comment: @AvidSeeker, so, what are you asking about again? The POSIX shell language specification, or concrete implementations of it? I first read your question as asking about a performance optimization, which I think falls in the realm of implementation details -- I don't think the specification goes into stuff like that, so it depends on the implementation. And there's no single _implementation_ that could be said to be "the" POSIX shell.

Comment: But if you're asking about the specification, then the answer should be clear, [_"The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing 'command' in a subshell environment (...)"_](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03). Nothing there about _not_ doing that. Besides, what would the difference be? A null command has null output anyway, so it doesn't matter if you "run" it or not.

Comment: In any case, subshell environments don't have to be implemented by forking a child process. ksh93 (and for a long time, ksh was the main reference for the POSIX sh specification) doesn't and you'll see the POSIX spec makes no reference to child process to describe subshell environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) [writes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772297/shell-detection-of-empty-subshell#comment1474789_772297), [POSIX itself specifies that](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)

> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command in a subshell environment (see [Shell Execution Environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12)) and replacing the command substitution (the text of *command* plus the enclosing `"$()"` or backquotes) with the standard output of the command, removing sequences of one or more <newline> characters at the end of the substitution.

However looking at shells’ actual behaviour reveals some surprises (well, one). I’m using a script containing only

```bash
echo \
Before \
`# commented` \
After
```

Bash and Zsh fork a subshell to run the comment-only command substitution:

```
$ strace -f -e process bash bttest
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "bttest"], 0x7ffe31522a10 /* 67 vars */) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLDstrace: Process 3134851 attached
, child_tidptr=0x7fe3ef0c6a10) = 3134851
[pid 3134851] exit_group(0)             = ?
[pid 3134851] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3134851, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 3134851
wait4(-1, 0x7ffecdd13810, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
Before After
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

```
$ strace -f -e process zsh bttest
execve("/usr/bin/zsh", ["zsh", "bttest"], 0x7fffa2f78140 /* 67 vars */) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLDstrace: Process 3134903 attached
, child_tidptr=0x7f236ce63750) = 3134903
[pid 3134903] exit_group(0)             = ?
[pid 3134902] kill(3134903, 0)          = 0
[pid 3134903] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3134903, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, {ru_utime={tv_sec=0, tv_usec=593}, ru_stime={tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}, ...}) = 3134903
wait4(-1, 0x7ffcabc4a7d4, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, 0x7ffcabc4a7f0) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
kill(3134903, 0)                        = -1 ESRCH (No such process)
Before After
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

[DASH](http://gondor.apana.org.au/%7Eherbert/dash/) on the other hand parses the contents inside the backticks to determine whether they represent a builtin command or an external command, and if that parsing results in an empty “node” (an empty command), [skips it entirely](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/eval.c?id=d5d616126ccc309d441fa82bb6a5bbf3377bd0e9#n634):

```
$ strace -f -e process dash bttest
execve("/bin/dash", ["dash", "bttest"], 0x7ffe61eee5c0 /* 67 vars */) = 0
Before After
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

If the backticks include a command, even a builtin, DASH does fork, same as Bash and Zsh; with

```bash
echo \
Before \
`: # commented` \
After
```

we get

```
$ strace -f -e process dash bttest
execve("/bin/dash", ["dash", "bttest"], 0x7fff762e6260 /* 41 vars */) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7effab920850) = 3905359
strace: Process 3905359 attached
[pid 3905359] exit_group(0)             = ?
[pid 3905359] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3905359, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 3905359
wait4(-1, 0x7ffdb1e8683c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
Before After
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So there is at least one shell “smart” enough to not launch a subshell in this scenario.

Some shells, such as ksh93, don’t fork at all for subshells not involving external commands; even with the `:` variant of the test, `strace` shows

```
$ strace -f -e process ksh93 bttest
execve("/bin/ksh93", ["ksh93", "bttest"], 0x7ffce3c73510 /* 41 vars */) = 0
Before After
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

(There is no “POSIX shell” — POSIX is a specification, with no reference implementations. No shell that I’m aware of strictly implements POSIX and only POSIX.)

Comment: Also note that ksh93 doesn't implement subshell environments using a child shell process, so you won't see a fork there either.

Comment: Indeed; I hadn’t shown that DASH forks for subshells when the backticks aren’t “empty”, unlike ksh93. I’ve added that to the answer, thanks!

Comment: Bash does seem to refrain from forking if the command substitution is actually empty, or only contains whitespace. Which makes sense in a way, but is also somewhat surprising since it probably doesn't come up very often. Zsh seems to fork for even `$()`.

Comment: Also worth noting that that's not valid POSIX sh syntax, POSIX explicitly states that (when searching for closing backquote) *if a non-escaped backquote is encountered within a shell comment, [...] undefined results occur.*